# VSCode on Mac - Cmd-S clears editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed the perl extension by Gerald Richter in VSCode, and for some reason Cmd-S clears the editor instead of saving the file. Similarly, when I select File->Save from the main menu, the whole content of the file is removed.

Similarly, File-> Save As... also deletes everything from the file.

This is on a Mac.

Any suggestions what causes this?

Comment: Did you already create an Issue for this on Github?  ( https://github.com/raix/vscode-perl-debug/issues, or where ever this code is )  If not, why not?

Comment: No, I have not. I thought it was a matter of my configuration, not the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the exact same thing. It's the "format on save" feature that does it, for reasons I haven't figured out yet.

You can disable that feature by adding this to your `settings.json` file:

```
"[perl]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```